# help me to write php code for this MySQL sql

Tags: php

```
CREATE TABLE articles
( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
, title VARCHAR(99) NOT NULL
, dateposted DATE NOT NULL
, author VARCHAR(99) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE article_rel
( this_article INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES articles (id)
, related_article INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES articles (id) 
, PRIMARY KEY (this_article,related_article)
);
```

I am building article site, where i want to show related article. I can write code for articles table , just scratching heads how to do with article_rel table.

Comment: Then write code for that table and use it to decide how to write code for the other table. If you have written any existing PHP then show it to us. We can't write your apps for you.

Comment: Not sure what you want here?  Are you looking for an OO implementation of this table in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  a.*
FROM
  articles a
INNER JOIN
  article_rel ar
    ON
  ar.this_article = SOME_ARTICLE_ID_HERE
    AND
  ar.related_article = a.id
```

Brain is fried, but I think that will do it.

Comment: Yes, given the schema provided, that should return the records from the `articles` table that are related to a given article id. Not that this is PHP code the OP seems to be asking for, but you've probably addressed his actual issue... :)